# use external function as member-function pointer

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointer-to-member

Is it possible in C++ to create a function which is not defined in class `A` but can be treated like a method pointer? Eg.:

```
typedef bool (A::*MethodType)(int a);

MethodType g_someMethod = &A::SomeMethod;
```

Now, I want to create a new function `AnotherMethod` which is of the type `MethodType`. I have tried to do the following:

```
bool A_AnotherMethod(A* _this, int a) {
    std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    return true;
}

MethodType g_someMethod = A_AnotherMethod;

// ...

(this->*g_someMethod )(42);
```

But I get

```
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'bool (__cdecl *)(A *,int)' to 'bool (__cdecl A::* )(int)'
```

How to do it correctly?

Comment: As far as I know, it isn't possible to do exactly what you're describing here, since `MethodType` needs to be applied to an object of type `A` if it points to a member, and can't be applied to such an object if it does not. However, there may be ways to get a similar effect, depending on the problem you're trying to solve - why do you want to be able to do this?

Comment: Can you change the type of `g_someMethod`?  `std::function<bool(A&,int)>` would be more flexible than the function pointer type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. C++ does not have a feature similar to extension methods in C#.

p.s. Method pointers have clumsy syntax in C++ and are rarely used. But this is the way how they are defined in the language.